# Subversion Server with Azure AD SSO

Tags: svn, entra-id, saml, openid, subversion-edge

There is a running CollabNet Subversion Edge Server in the current version 5.2.4.
It is currently connected with LDAP for authentication.

Now there is a challenge to grant permission to b2b guests of our azure ad to use this SVN.
Is there any way to connect SubVersion Edge to Azure AD for authentication? Or is there any buyable solution to get this run?
Or is there another SVN server which is able to authenticate with Azure AD (OpenId/SAML)?

I have searched a lot of time, but it seems not usual to connect a 90s application to a 21th century technology.